# Data Transfer Object in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

May I know how to transfer Object in CodeIgnitor. Is the below way is correct?

```
class UserLibrary{

private $username;

public getUsername() {
        return this->username;
    }
    public void setUsername(username) {
        this->username = username;
    }

}
```

//Setting the Value

```
$Reg = new UserLibrary;
    $Reg->setName(name);
```

// how to get the value ?

Answer (score 1):

There is something seriously wrong with your php code.

As in CodeIgniter your library classes should be placed within your **application/libraries** folder, as this is where CodeIgniter will look for them when they are initialized.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Userlibrary {

    private $username;

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }
    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }
}

/* End of file Userlibrary.php */
```

To load your library, you should load it in your **controller** as such:

```
$this->load->library('userlibrary');
```

Then you can use your library as follow:

```
$this->userlibrary->setUsername('your username');
echo $this->userlibrary->getUsername();
```

For more information use the official documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html